# using .map (or another stdlib feature) to create a hash not array

Tags: arrays, hash, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to target JMS servers in the cloud, the puppet module init.pp needs to add a key to a hash.

I'm reading a block of hiera and having to extract parts of it to form a new hash.  .each doesn't return any values so I'm using .map.
The values I'm getting out are exactly as I want, however when I tried a deep_merge I discovered that .map outputs as an array.

service.yaml

```
jms_subdeployment_instances:
   'BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM':
      ensure:     'present'
      target:
       - 'BPMJMSServer_auto_1'
       - "BPMJMSServer_auto_%{::ec2_tag_name}"
      targettype:
        - 'JMSServer'
        - 'JMSServer'
```

init.pp

````
  $jms_subdeployments = lookup('jms_subdeployment_instances', $default_params)
  $jms_target_args = $jms_subdeployments.map |$subdep, $value| {
    $jms_short_name = $subdep[0, 3]
    $jms_subdeployment_inst = $array_domain_jmsserver_addresses.map |$index, $server| {
      "${jms_short_name}JMSServer_auto_${server}"

      if defined('$jms_subdeployment_inst') {
        $jmsTargetArg = {
          "${subdep}" => {
            'target' => $jms_subdeployment_inst
          }
        }
      }
    }

  $merge_subdeployment_targets = merge($jms_subdeployments, $jms_target_args)



```Output
New JMS targets are : [{BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM => {target => [BPMJMSServer_auto_server101, BPMJMSServer_auto_server102]}}]
````

The enclosing [ ] are causing me trouble.  As far as I can see, in puppet .to_h doesn't work either

Thanks

Update 22/07/2019:

Thanks for the reply, I've had to tweak it slightly because puppet was failing with "Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Method call, 'values' parameter 'hsh' expects a Hash value, got Tuple"

```
  $array_domain_jmsserver_addresses = 
  any2array(hiera('pdb_domain_msserver_addresses'))
  $array_domain_jmsserver_addresses.sort()
  $jms_subdeployments = lookup('jms_subdeployment_instances', $default_params)
  $hash_domain_jmsserver_addresses = Hash($array_domain_jmsserver_addresses)

  if $hash_domain_jmsserver_addresses.length > 0 {
      $jms_target_arg_tuples = $jms_subdeployments.keys.map |$subdep| {
      $jms_short_name = $subdep[0, 3]
      $jms_subdeployment_inst = regsubst(
          $hash_domain_jmsserver_addresses.values, /^/, "${jms_short_name}JMSServer_auto_")

  # the (key, value) tuple to which this element maps
  [ $subdep, { 'target' => $jms_subdeployment_inst } ]
}

$jms_target_args = Hash($jms_target_arg_tuples)
} else {
$jms_target_args = {}
}

notify{"Normal array is : ${jms_subdeployments}": }
notify{"Second array is : ${jms_target_args}": }  

$merge_subdeployment_targets = deep_merge($jms_subdeployments, $jms_target_args)
notify{"Merged array is : ${merge_subdeployment_targets}": }
```

> Normal is : {BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM => {ensure => present, target => [BPMJMSServer_auto_1, BPMJMSServer_auto_server1], targettype => [JMSServer, JMSServer]},
>
> Second is : {BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM => {target => [BPMJMSServer_auto_server2]}
>
> Merged is : {BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM => {ensure => present, target => [BPMJMSServer_auto_server2], targettype => [JMSServer, JMSServer]}

Desired output it:

> {BPMJMSModuleUDDs:BPMJMSSubDM => {ensure => present, target => [BPMJMSServer_auto_1, BPMJMSServer_auto_server1, BPMJMSServer_auto_server2], targettype => [JMSServer, JMSServer, JMSServer]}

Comment: Your code has unbalanced parentheses.  I *think* I've figured out what you mean, but if so then your code also has inconsistent indentation.

Comment: If the (different) revision in my answer does not resolve the problem, then how about moving closer to a [mre] by replacing all the `lookup()` calls with literals.  The code I presented in my answer is an adaptation of your original code, but if that's not well suited to the actual data in the first place then we don't have sufficient information to get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

> when I tried a deep_merge I discovered that .map outputs as an array.

Yes, this is [its documented behavior](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#map).  `map()` should be considered a function on the *elements* of a collection, not on the collection overall, and the results are always provided as an array.

It would probably be useful to look over the alternatives for [converting values to hashes](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#conversion-to-hash-and-struct).  Particularly attractive is this one:

> - An `Array` matching `Array[Tuple[Any,Any], 1]` is converted to a hash where each tuple describes a key/value entry

To make use of this, map each entry to a (key, value) tuple, and convert the resulting array of tuples to a hash.  A conversion of your attempt to that approach might look something like this:

```
if $array_domain_jmsserver_addresses.length > 0 {
  $jms_target_arg_tuples = $jms_subdeployments.keys.map |$subdep| {
    $jms_short_name = $subdep[0, 3]
    $jms_subdeployment_inst = regsubst(
        $array_domain_jmsserver_addresses.sort, /^/, "${jms_short_name}JMSServer_auto_")

    # the (key, value) tuple to which this element maps
    [ $subdep, { 'target' => $jms_subdeployment_inst } ]
  }

  $jms_target_args = Hash($jms_target_arg_tuples)
} else {
  $jms_target_args = {}
}

$merge_subdeployment_targets = merge($jms_subdeployments, $jms_target_args)
```

Note that since you don't use the values of `$jms_subdeployments`, I have taken the liberty of simplifying your code somewhat by applying the `keys()` function to it.  I have also used `regsubst()` instead of `map()` to form target names from the elements of `$array_domain_jmsserver_addresses`, which I personally find more readable in this case, especially since you were not using the indexes.

I've also inferred what I think you meant your `if defined()` test to accomplish, and replaced it with the outermost test of the length of the `$array_domain_jmsserver_addresses` array.  One could also write it in somewhat more functional form, by building the hash without regard to whether there are any targets, and then `filter()`ing it after, but that seems wasteful because it appears that either all entries will have (the same) targets, or none will.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed reply, I've updated the original question.  Interestingly the merge isn't quite working as yet

Comment: @DaveShaw, I have tweaked the code in this answer appropriately for `$array_domain_jmsserver_addresses` being an array rather than a hash.